# Presto hive connector reads .zst file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, presto, zstd

for the following query, both Hive and Spark-SQL work fine,

but the result returned by **Presto** (hive connector ) has wrong encoding/decoding.

Wonders how should I set the hive connector, or presto doesn't support reading zstd?

- hive table:

  ```bash
  CREATE TABLE mydb.testtb (
    mid varchar COMMENT 'mid',
    day varchar
  )
  WITH (
      external_location = 'hdfs://userx/mydb/testtb/
      format = 'TEXTFILE',
      partitioned_by = ARRAY['day']
  )
  ```
- files pointing to the HDFS are written using `zstd` compression like

  `.../testtb/day=20221113/part-00020-63c1xxxxx000.zst`
- SQL

  `select * from mydb.testtb where day=20221113 limit 5`

result of presto
[image]

Comment: Can you query table from Hive directly using Presto instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Hi @PrabhakarReddy I have tried it but not works.  the `create table xx` above just for showing the schema.